# onEdit Update Sheet2 when Sheet1 is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the full scenario:

I have an add-on on google spreadsheets where it extracts daily data from a certain source, the problem with that add-on is it only extracts data on a daily basis, overwriting the previous data, so to solve the problem, I created a second sheet where I append the data everyday. Now, I'm wondering if there is a script that once the add-on edited the sheet1 it will automatically append sheet2

Comment: Describe your workflow more closely. Probably SO already has the solution. But it's impossible to suggest you anything without the details.

Comment: sorry for being vague, already edited the post

Comment: Well. The trigger `onEdit()` wont work. It works only when you're changing the sheet manually. Probably you have to use time driven trigger that will run a function every 24 hours. Here is example of the function that grabs all the data from one sheet and append it to another sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543471/iterate-through-column-a-and-do-until-empty-cell

Comment: Here is the example how you can add the time driven trigger to run a function every day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191648/edit-a-column-in-google-sheets-based-on-a-condition

Comment: So all you need is to combine the two answers and tweak the code a bit to fit your spreadsheet (change the sheet names and change function names). I can't do it because I don't know the names of your sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it can be done with this code:

```
// function to appednd all the data from Sheet1 at the bottom of Sheet2
function copy_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src_range = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var last_row = dest_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange('A' + last_row);
  src_range.copyTo(dest_range);
}

// function to install the trigger
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("copy_sheet")
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}

// function to remove all triggers
function delete_all_triggers() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
    .forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
}
```

You have to run manually the function `installTrigger()` to install the trigger and then it will run the function `copy_sheet()` automatically every day. It's up to you to change the name of the sheets to fit your actual spreadsheet.

To test you can change temporary the line:

```
.everyDays(1)
```

to:

```
.everyMinutes(1)
```

It will copy the data every minute.

**Ref:**

- [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Not sure if it will work but you can try to use the trigger `onChange()`. Just rename the function (and run it once just in case), install the trigger and wait:

```
function onChange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src_range = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var last_row = dest_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange('A' + last_row);
  src_range.copyTo(dest_range);
}

function install_trigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

**Ref:**

- [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange)

Comment: Hey! thanks for this! question, what is the purpose of function delete_all_triggers()?

Comment: tried the onChange, do I need to run it once? and then it will just automatically append whenever there's a change in sheet1?

Comment: The function `install_trigger()` installs the trigger. It needs to run just once. The function `remove_all_triggers()` removes all triggers from the project in case you don't need them anymore. Actually you can install and remove triggers manually from the menu in Script Editor